# SDL not rendering pixels

Tags: c++, sdl, pixel

I'm trying to change the background color of my window in SDL with pixel level access (I'm making a particle explosion), but the background is staying white.

First I tried using memset to set the memory of the pixels to 0x00 to change the color to black (I used memset because I am following a tutorial that used it)

`memset(buffer, 0x00, SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT * sizeof(Uint32));`

Since that didn't work I looked up how to change the draw color of the renderer and came up with:

`SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 255);`

Here is my Texture, Renderer, and Buffer code, and how I set up the window (SCREEN_WIDTH and SCREEN_HEIGHT are const ints set to 800 and 600 respectively):

```
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Fire Particle Explosion", 
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
Uint32* buffer = new Uint32[SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT];

SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, buffer, SCREEN_WIDTH * sizeof(Uint32));
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

How would I properly change the background pixel by pixel, and why do neither of the ways I attempted work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manipulate a buffer in memory to achieve that, and you may not need a texture. The recommended way is to use the "2D Accelerated Rendering" functions in SDL2.

First of all, start without the "SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC" parameter, use '0' instead. On Linux, some old graphics drivers produce flickering with that flag.

This should erase the screen in black:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 255);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
```

I strongly advise you to use [SDL_RenderDrawPoint()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawPoint) in order to update the screen pixel by pixel. It is hardware accelerated.

Basically, here is what happens in your game loop:

```
- set the color to black, then erase the screen with SDL_RenderClear()
- for each point to draw, first set the draw color, then draw the point
- use SDL_RenderPresent()
```

I have written a small example of SDL2 code in C for making particle explosions: [drawpoints](https://bitbucket.org/josephpaul0/drawpoints)

Comment: Even when commenting out all the buffer and texture code, and switching 'SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC' to '0', 

`SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 255);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);`

is not changing the color of the background to black. I tried to look at your example but I am new to C++ and don't understand many of the things you use (ex. #define instead of static const, kbs, typedef struct, etc.). Any idea why it is not rendering the screen black with those two lines (still no errors or warnings)

Comment: I think that you are trying to go too fast. You should begin with learning C programming before jumping into SDL programming. Once you feel ready, then do the tutorials at http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/.

Comment: I want to learn C++ not C, I feel if I learn C first I will get the two confused later on. I know a small amount of C++ (see https://www.udemy.com/free-learn-c-tutorial-beginners/, I'm at the particle effects tutorial). Lastly, I have no intent of ever using SDL, it is just being used as a medium to teach how to create a whole project using what was learned in the rest of the tutorial.